# yarn build locally and on server builds in different environments

Tags: webpack, package.json

I have very strange situation.

Same code I have locally on computer and also on server.
Code on server is copy of local code.
Alse I can check, open both codes local and on server and compare them, code is same.

Both of my `package.json` files (local and on server) has:

```
"scripts": {
   "build": "webpack --config webpack.build.js 
}
```

When I do: yarn build, in `webpack.build.js` I have `console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)` locally I got result is: `production`, but when I do same on server I got `development` from `console.log`.

It is vary strange to me, does someone knows how this happened?

Answer (score 1):

I found what was issue.

In file `webpack.build.js` publicPath was set like:

`const publicPath = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? '/foo/ : '/bar/;`

When I locally run `yarn build` which runs `webpack.build.js` file and do `console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)` I got `undefined`.

However when I run on server `yarn build` which runs `webpack.build.js` file and do `console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)` I got `development`.

Somehow my server is set to run in development mode by default.

I know that: `Node.js assumes it's always running in a development environment`, but on my local it is not the case.

I will have to do more research, maybe some default `NODE_ENV` is set in `dotenv` or some config file.